# Array Limit By Case

Tags: php, arrays, function, sorting, element

Is there some type of select function of sorts to create a new array selecting only certain elements with sub elements matching cases? For example, I would only like to have an array containing where [type] is "A", so have a final array only containing [1] and [2].

```
[1]  
    [type] => A
    [month] => January

[2]
    [type] => A
    [month] => February

[3]
    [type] => B
    [month] => March
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function is_type_a($element) { return $element['type'] === 'A'; }
$fiteredArray = array_filter($inputArray, 'is_type_a');
```

You can do that more concisely with an anonymous function if you have PHP 5.4.

Comment: What is $element in this function? Isn't $element['type'] suggesting that $element is the same as $inputArray?

Comment: No, $element[0] would be if $element == $inputArray. array_filter passes every top level element from the input array to your callback function (is_type_a). So it would pass $inputArray[0], $inputArray[1]...etc/ http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Alrighty it works - I guess I'm just stumbling on what $element is... Either way it works and the link to the manual helped too :P

Comment: `array_filter` loops through the big array calling `is_type_a()` on every element of it.  Given your array, the first element is at index 1, so first it calls `is_type_a($inputArray[1])`.  Inside `is_type_a`, `$element` would be the same as `$inputArray[1]`, which would be `array([type]=>A,[month]=>January)`. The second call, `$element` will be `$inputArray[2]`.  And so on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Appreciate it a lot! <3

Answer (score 1):

You could just reduce that array to the entries you want. Keep in mind this will preserve the original keys, So you may end up with an array that has 0, 1, and 3 as keys if 2 was unset during the process.

```
foreach( $array as $key => &$value ){
  if ( $value['type'] != 'A' )
    unset( $array[ $key ] );
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/OG5rguJ8

Another method is to use `array_filter` to iteratively reduce the array one entry at a time:

```
function callbackFunc( $val ) {
    return $val['type'] == 'A';
}

$result = array_filter( $array, callbackFunc );
```

We call the `array_filter` method passing in the array we'd like to filter, as well as the filtering function we've created. Our function will be ran against each element within the array, treating the current element as a `$val` variable.

If that variable's type key maps to a value that is `==` to "A", `TRUE` is returned. Otherwise, `FALSE` is returned. When the function returns `TRUE`, the evaluated value is sent to the `$result` array. If `FALSE` was returned, the value is not pushed onto the `$result` array.

Like the previous option, this method will also preserve the key values.

Demo: http://codepad.org/todHBZo7

Comment: Awesome it works! Do you think this is an effective method? I have a massive array I need to shrink - not sure how much time this would take relative to something else!

Comment: @KevinMurphy There are many ways to go about this to be completely honest. I don't know what your project requires, so I cannot speak to which method is best for you.

Comment: The original keys is exactly what I want anyways so this is perfect :P

Answer (score 0):

```
function select_custom($array,$param)
{
    foreach($array as $k=>$v)
    {
       if($v['type']==$param)
       {
          $returnArray[] = $v; 
       }
    }
    return $returnArray;
}
```

Comment: check it out, I did'nt test. should be fast

Comment: did u give the second parameter to the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_splice() if you know the indexes of the elements you want to pick, if not as suggested by previous answers, you have to loop